# How to determine length of X509 Public Key

Tags: java, x509certificate, x509

How do I determine the length (in bits) of an X509 Public Key in Java?

I'm looking to get the same value as "Public-Key" when running "openssl x509 -in cert.crt -noout -text".  For example:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            17:00:00:01:a2:41:4b:56:3e:99:ba:92:b5:00:02:00:00:01:a2
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: DC=com, DC=magnicomp, CN=MagniComp Issuing CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 14 17:23:18 2015 GMT
            Not After : Sep 13 17:23:18 2016 GMT
        Subject: CN=dim.magnicomp.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
```

I've got an X509Certificate object and I've played around with the PublicKey value returned via `getPublicKey()` but I can't seem to figure out how to determine the key length from this.

Answer (score 11):

Snippet from [EJBCA](https://www.ejbca.org/) source code [org.ejbca.util.keystore.KeyTools](https://svn.cesecore.eu/svn/ejbca/branches/Branch_4_0/ejbca/src/java/org/ejbca/util/keystore/KeyTools.java)#getKeyLength to calculate key length from public key of various algorithms:

```
/**
 * Gets the key length of supported keys
 * @param pk PublicKey used to derive the keysize
 * @return -1 if key is unsupported, otherwise a number >= 0. 0 usually means the length can not be calculated, 
 * for example if the key is an EC key and the "implicitlyCA" encoding is used.
 */
public static int getKeyLength(final PublicKey pk) {
    int len = -1;
    if (pk instanceof RSAPublicKey) {
        final RSAPublicKey rsapub = (RSAPublicKey) pk;
        len = rsapub.getModulus().bitLength();
    } else if (pk instanceof JCEECPublicKey) {
        final JCEECPublicKey ecpriv = (JCEECPublicKey) pk;
        final org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec spec = ecpriv.getParameters();
        if (spec != null) {
            len = spec.getN().bitLength();              
        } else {
            // We support the key, but we don't know the key length
            len = 0;
        }
    } else if (pk instanceof ECPublicKey) {
        final ECPublicKey ecpriv = (ECPublicKey) pk;
        final java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec spec = ecpriv.getParams();
        if (spec != null) {
            len = spec.getOrder().bitLength(); // does this really return something we expect?
        } else {
            // We support the key, but we don't know the key length
            len = 0;
        }
    } else if (pk instanceof DSAPublicKey) {
        final DSAPublicKey dsapub = (DSAPublicKey) pk;
        if ( dsapub.getParams() != null ) {
            len = dsapub.getParams().getP().bitLength();
        } else {
            len = dsapub.getY().bitLength();
        }
    } 
    return len;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you know that the algorithm used was RSA, you can cast the public key to a [`RSAPublicKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPublicKey.html) and get the key length using [`getModulus()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAKey.html#getModulus--):

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("certificate.pem");
CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) f.generateCertificate(fin);
RSAPublicKey rsaPk = (RSAPublicKey) certificate.getPublicKey();
System.out.println(rsaPk.getModulus().bitLength());
```

For a DSA public key, you need to check the bit length of the prime and the subprime used, obtained with [`getP()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/DSAParams.html#getP--) and [`getQ()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/DSAParams.html#getQ--):

```
DSAPublicKey dsaPk = (DSAPublicKey) certificate.getPublicKey();
System.out.println(dsaPk.getParams().getP().bitLength());
System.out.println(dsaPk.getParams().getQ().bitLength());
```

Comment: That method does work for me for RSAPublicKey instances. Thank you!  I would love to hear if anybody has a more generic method.

Comment: @MikeCooper I edited my post to show an example with DSA keys. There is no generic solution, each time you need to cast to the explicit public key interface and get the key length from there.

Comment: Thanks for the DSAPublicKey example.  Perhaps though I should just use DSAPublicKey.getY().bitLength()?